# Spark Dataframe script running very slow

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm quite new to Big Data and currently learning Spark. I have installed Spark 2.0 on my windows laptop and created a script using Spark Dataframe api with python 3.4 to find the sum of 1 specific column. It is **taking too long approx. 5mins and 3 seconds**.

This text file is very big ( approx 500mb ) with **2.4 million records**. 

Task manager shows **100% CPU** consumption and **50% RAM** consumption.

Here is what i did:

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

def mapLogs(line):
    fields = line.split("|")
    return Row(userID=int(fields[0]), trackID=int(fields[1]), shared=int(fields[2]), radio=int(fields[3]), skip=int(fields[4]))

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","file:///F:/temp")\
    .appName("MusciTrackShared")\
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("bigTextFile.txt")          # format : UserId|TrackId|Shared|Radio|Skip
music_logs = lines.map(mapLogs)                                 # convert each line to Row

df = spark.createDataFrame(music_logs)                          # create dataframe

df.filter(df['shared'] == 1).groupBy(df['trackID']).sum('shared').orderBy("sum(shared)", ascending=False).show(5)

spark.stop()
```

What am I doing wrong here ?Can anybody point me in right direction please ?

Thanks

Comment: Pig script for the same query and test data takes 3min on ubuntu in Vm.  Spark is supposed to work faster than that right?

Comment: I rewrote tge same program in saprk using basic RDD commands and it still takes 5min 1 seconds.

Comment: 14 hrs have gone by and not a single comment from community.  I'm really surprised.

Comment: 3 minutes is OK. 3 hours is not